# Cannot Get The Texture Showed Up Correctly glDrawElements

Tags: opengl, c++, textures, c

I still have  this problem almost 1 month. Tried to search on Google but did not find any solution to this. I have loaded all the data correctly but don't know why the texture came up like this.

Here is my loader:

Header

```
struct SVertex
{
public:
    float X, Y, Z;
};

struct STexture
{
public:
    float U, V;
};

struct SFace
{
public:
    int X, Y, Z;
};

class CBMap
{
public:
    struct SMesh
    {
        SVertex *Vertex;
        SVertex *Normal;
        STexture *TexCoord;
        SFace *Face;
        SFace *FaceNormal;

        char Texture[32];
        int TextureID;
        int TotalVertice;
        int TotalNormal;
        int TotalFace;
    };

    SMesh* Mesh;

    CBMap();
    ~CBMap();

    int TotalMesh;

    int Load(char* szFile);
    int Get_FileHeader(FILE* pFile);
    int Get_TotalMesh(FILE* pFile);
    int GetData(FILE* pFile);
};
```

CPP

```
int CBMap::Load(char* szFile)
{
    FILE* pFile = fopen(szFile, "r");

    if (!pFile) return 0;

    int iBMap = Get_FileHeader(pFile);

    if (!iBMap)
    {
        printf("BMAP file is not valid\n");
        return 0;
    }

    TotalMesh   = Get_TotalMesh(pFile);
    Mesh        = new SMesh[TotalMesh];
    GetData(pFile);

    int iMesh = 0;

    char* pJunk;
    char szHeader[32];

    while (!feof(pFile))
    {
        fscanf(pFile, "%s", &szHeader);

        if (!strncmp(szHeader, "BMAP", 4)) continue;
        if (!strncmp(szHeader, "mesh", 4)) continue;
        if (!strncmp(szHeader, "mtl", 3))
        {
            fscanf(pFile, "%s", Mesh[iMesh].Texture);
            Mesh[iMesh].TextureID = LoadTexture(Mesh[iMesh].Texture);
        }

        if (!strncmp(szHeader, "ve", 2))
        {
            fscanf(pFile, "%d", &pJunk);
            Mesh[iMesh].Vertex = (SVertex*)malloc(sizeof (SVertex) * Mesh[iMesh].TotalVertice);

            for (int i = 0; i < Mesh[iMesh].TotalVertice; ++i)
            {
                fscanf(pFile, "%f %f %f", &Mesh[iMesh].Vertex[i].X, &Mesh[iMesh].Vertex[i].Y, &Mesh[iMesh].Vertex[i].Z);
            }
        }

        if (!strncmp(szHeader, "uv", 2))
        {
            fscanf(pFile, "%d", &pJunk);
            Mesh[iMesh].TexCoord = (STexture*)malloc(sizeof (STexture) * Mesh[iMesh].TotalVertice);

            for (int i = 0; i < Mesh[iMesh].TotalVertice; ++i)
            {
                fscanf(pFile, "%f %f", &Mesh[iMesh].TexCoord[i].U, &Mesh[iMesh].TexCoord[i].V);
            }
        }

        if (!strncmp(szHeader, "vn", 2))
        {
            fscanf(pFile, "%d", &pJunk);
            Mesh[iMesh].Normal = (SVertex*)malloc(sizeof (SVertex) * Mesh[iMesh].TotalNormal);

            for (int i = 0; i < Mesh[iMesh].TotalNormal; ++i)
            {
                fscanf(pFile, "%f %f %f", &Mesh[iMesh].Normal[i].X, &Mesh[iMesh].Normal[i].Y, &Mesh[iMesh].Normal[i].Z);
            }
        }

        if (!strncmp(szHeader, "f", 1))
        {
            fscanf(pFile, "%d", &pJunk);
            Mesh[iMesh].Face = (SFace*)malloc(sizeof (SFace) * Mesh[iMesh].TotalFace * 3);
            Mesh[iMesh].FaceNormal = (SFace*)malloc(sizeof (SFace) * Mesh[iMesh].TotalFace * 3);

            for (int i = 0; i < Mesh[iMesh].TotalFace; ++i)
            {
                fscanf(pFile, "%d %d %d %d %d %d",  &Mesh[iMesh].Face[i].X, &Mesh[iMesh].Face[i].Y, &Mesh[iMesh].Face[i].Z,
                                                    &Mesh[iMesh].FaceNormal[i].X, &Mesh[iMesh].FaceNormal[i].Y, &Mesh[iMesh].FaceNormal[i].Z);
            }
        }

        if (!strncmp(szHeader, "end", 3))
        {
            if (iMesh < TotalMesh) iMesh ++;
        }
    }

    printf("CBMap::Model Loaded\n");

    fclose(pFile);
    return 1;
}
```

First picture is reality and second picture expectation

[image: Reality]
[image: Expectation]

Comment: We can barely see the picture. It's too dark. Is this the problem? If not, what do you mean by "the texture came up like this"? Please provide more context and also describe or better show a desired result.

Comment: I needed to set the v components to v = 1 - loadedV. this is because opengl uses a different origin for the texture coordinate system than directx

Comment: Thanks Tobias but I don't really understand what you explain. Any example?

Comment: Tobias, thank you very much, that makes my code works. How to flag your comment as an answer?

Comment: I postet it as answer. When I wrote the comment I wasn't sure about it and didn't have the time to research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DirectX and OpenGl have different coordinate systems for their texture coordinates. OpenGl uses a origin in the lower left but your model assumes that the origin is in the upper left.
Because of that you need to mirror the UV coordinates or your images along the y axis.
You can do so by setting the v component to 1 - loadedV.

Comment: Thank you very much Tobias, now the texture showed up correctly.